# Java - "Unhandled exception" though it's actually handled

Tags: java, exception, javac

I have a setup similar to below. In AClass the Java compiler in line `throws e` complains  -

`Unhandled exception: <path-to>.DatastoreException`

(Editable share from jdoodle - [jdoodle.com/a/2xbl](https://jdoodle.com/a/2xbl))

Why is that? Aren't I only throwing if the exception is an IllegalArgumentException?

```
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import <path-to>.DependencyException;
import <path-to>.DatastoreException;

public class AClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        try {
            new BClass().thisThrowsDatastoreException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
                throw e; //Javac complains in this line
            } else if (e instance of DatastoreException) {
                throw new DependencyException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BClass {

    public BClass() {}
    
    public void thisThrowsDatastoreException() throws DatastoreException {
        throw new DatastoreException();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DatastoreException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2L;
    public DatastoreException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DependencyException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    public DependencyException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it might be complaining about whatever calls `something()`, not the line you have noted as the problem.  Can you turn this into a [mcve] so we can verify it's working as you indicate?

Comment: How similar is it to above code? Because `throws Exception` would always indicate *any* exception, including runtime exceptions... I think an [mcve] is required as well (yeah, yeah, just testing the smart tags :P). Note that, after testing, the compiler still doesn't know that `e` is an `IllegalArgumentException`, because that's only a consequence of what happens during testing at runtime (I'm wondering if the latest versions of Java solve that particular issue, hmmm).

Comment: @markspace - I've added a JDoodle link - the issue is replicated there, if you want to check!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Minimal reproducible example in the Jdoodle link I've added to the question. Please see if that helps!

Comment: @markspace Respectfully, regardless of my presumed insanity, I'd really appreciate an answer to the actual question! :)

Comment: So I copied the code from some other website, and you **did NOT** put the `throws Exception` on `someMethod()`.  If I add that line, the compiler does not complain.  Your error is not reproducible.

Comment: @markspace The actual question is why that line asks me to handle a 'DatastoreException' while actually I'm only throwing an 'IllegalArgumentException' in that line. Quoting myself - "Aren't I only throwing if the exception is an IllegalArgumentException?"

Comment: You are throwing two exception from someMethod but they are not declared. your declaration should public void someMethod() throws Exception { .... } and if you want to more exception to throw even if there is then throw as RuntimeException, java compiler do not enforce RuntimeException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you're throwing in after checking `instanceof`, that's a runtime check, and `e` is still declared as `Exception`. While the compiler *could* infer from this that that line will only ever throw instances of `IllegalArgumentException`, that's not something it currently does (I guess it might with `instanceof` pattern matching in the future).

So, change

```java
if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
    throw e; //Javac complains in this 
}
```

to

```java
if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
    throw (IllegalArgumentException) e;
}
```

Comment: `someMethod()` is marked to throw `Exception` so why would the system complain if it thinks that method is throwing `e` of type `Exception`?

Comment: @markspace - Agreed, that was a manual error. Please check the jdoodle link!

Comment: @Anusha Maybe not, but most IDE's will allow you to smartly solve it for you, so you can just return `e` and then let the IDE add the cast (e.g. using <ctrl><1> in Eclipse).

Comment: It would probably be better to use `catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { throw e; } catch (Exception e) { throw new DependencyException(e); }`. The catch already does an `instanceof` check for you, why do it more verbosely inside a catch?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I like that a lot better, actually!